# How to freeze Tensorflow model to .pb without a .meta checkpoint file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

According to [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9716#issuecomment-775511012), TF 2._ doesn't save .meta files to checkpoint anymore. All answers I could find online as to "how to convert checkpoint file to model" work with the .meta file whereas `Checkpoint.save()` didn't save any .meta files for me.

Is it still possible to convert some of my .data-00000-of-00001 checkpoints to .pb?

Edit: It seems the most practical solution is to choose the checkpoint you want to save, edit the 'checkpoint' file in your checkpoints directory, restore "latest" checkpoint (i.e., whichever one you specified in the 'checkpoint' file), then save with `model.save()`.

Comment: Why not just restore your model at checkpoint `x` and then save it as pb or h5

Comment: @AloneTogether the last time I did this, I could only restore each checkpoint file one time before it was no longer restorable for some reason (results upon consequent restores were just noise typical of a pre-trained model), which has left me a little scared since I lost about 20 hours of training. Additionally I have over a dozen checkpoints all of which I wish to restore and I don't know how to go about saving all of them safely. I'm new to ML so sorry if this is nooby.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned in the edit part of your question, you can restore the checkpoint using the `load_weights` method and then can save the same model using `model.save()` to get the `.pb` file. Please check this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/375a7dedd9c641dbd8ce2690032590a9/73909017.ipynb) for your reference